# Java: How can I add a JMenu to a JPanel or create a drop down button?

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, menuitem, menubar

is there any way to add a JMenuItem to a JPanel so that I can create a button to show multiple options, like the latest news button in firefox, under the address bar?

I can only add JMenu and JMenuItems to a JMenuBar, JPopupMenu and other JMenus and JMenuitems

Is there any way to create in Java Swing a drop down Jbutton? (the ones with an down arrow in their left which shows more options to the user)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. If you have a code illustrating your solution, it might be interesting to publish it as an answer (and choose your own entry as the official answer if you want)

Comment: thx, i did it, but i have to wait 48 hours to vote my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finnally i implement the "show options button" with a simple Jutton, and a JPopupPane with the options to show:

In the ActionPerformedListener of the button i write this code:

```
popMenu.show(showOptionsButton,0,showOptionsButton.getHeight())
```

It works fine like a JMenu in a JMenuBar, but not exactly like a dropdown button, in which you can perform an action pressing the button or show more actions pressing the down arrow. I believe this can be done ussing two buttons "very close", then use the code above in the arrow button, but setting the "action button" as the component of the popup, so that the popup shows below of both buttons.

Answer (score 3):

A `JMenuBar` should only be added to a `JFrame` (`setMenuBar()`), not a `JPanel`.

A Swing drop down button is the way to go here.

See this [article](http://java.dzone.com/news/drop-down-buttons-swing-new-al) for a good discussion on various implementation propositions

[alt text http://blogs.sun.com/geertjan/resource/dropdownbutton1-jl.png](http://blogs.sun.com/geertjan/resource/dropdownbutton1-jl.png)

The above drop-down button use the **NetBeans UI Utilities API** (`platform7/modules/org-openide-awt.jar` in any distribution of NetBeans IDE). You do not need to have NetBeans to run it: only this jar you have extracted from the NetBeans installation.

Comment: It works but i finnally not use it in order to not depend of an external jar in the app, which is distributed by JavaWebStart. I do it by showing a popmenu on point 0,comp.getHeight() of the button